# Get data Laravel 9 Vue js 3

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js

I need to get data for status = 1 or status = 2 in a table. I have done for status = 1 .please instruct me to do this. My code is as follows.

```
public function depositAccountIndex()
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
        return response()->json(Account::latest()->where('user', $userId)->where('status', 1 )->get());
    }
```

Comment: Well, start learning bye and Laravel and eventually you will be able to answer yourself. SO won’t help you here

Comment: Instead of `where('status', 1 )`, try `whereIn('status', [1,2])`